# Laravel: How to use where clause on both parent and child model in one to many relation

Tags: laravel, relationship

Table: groups

```
id name status
```

Table: items

```
id group_id name publish
```

Model: Group

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
```

Now I want to get all group models where status is running and then all related item models where publish is published.

I do this...

```
$query = Group::where('status', 'running')->items()->where('publish', 'published')->get();
```

that shows the following Error Message.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::items()
```

What's the wrong?
Is there any way to do this?

**Note this EDIT:**
`**How will I get all item models where group model's status is running and item model's publish is published.**`

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, the query should look like this

```
$result = Group::whereHas('items', function($query){
              $query->where("publish","published");
          })
          ->where("status", "running")
          ->select('items')
          ->get();
```

`$result` will have all `groups` with `status` as `running` and all 'items' with `publish` status as `published`.

Comment: This works fine. I could not properly ask my question. My exact question is:
How will I get all item models where group model's status is running and item model's publish is published.

Comment: So you want `items` out of this query?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to add `items` in your `select()` and it will only return that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$users = Group::whereHas('items', function($q){
    $q->where('publish', 'published');
})
->where('status', 'running')
->get();
```